# Pygame Screen is Black for Short Time, Then Closes

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4, cx-freeze

A game that I have been working on recently stopped working after converting it to .msi or .exe with cx_freeze. The first version worked perfectly fine, but now when I try to open the application, it just doesn't work.

It displays no error codes either. All it does is display a black screen and close. My code can be found below:

SpaceDodge.py

```
"""
Game Developer: Austin H.
Game Owner: Austin H.
Licensed Through: theoiestinapps
Build: 2
Version: 1.0.1
"""

import os
import pygame as pygame
import random
import sys
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.font.init()

left = False
right = False
playerDead = False
devMode = False
musicStopped = False

game_completed = False
game_level_score = (0)
game_display_score = (0)
deaths_this_session = (0)

user_teleport_active = False
user_health_active = False
user_health_inactive = False
user_teleport_display_active = ("False")
user_health_display_active = ("False")

display_width = 1280
display_height = 650

customOrange = (210, 121, 19)
customBlue = (17, 126, 194)
black = (0, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
green = (0, 225, 0)
red = (250, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Dodge")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

backgroundMusic = pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/Program Files/Space Dodge/game_background_music.mp3')
enemyImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Program Files/Space Dodge/enemy_image.png')
enemytwoImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Program Files/Space Dodge/enemy_image_two.png')
backgroundImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Program Files/Space Dodge/background_image.png')
rocketImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Program Files/Space Dodge/player_image.png')
injuredSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:/Program Files/Space Dodge/player_hurt_sound.wav')
errorSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:/Program Files/Space Dodge/game_error_sound.wav')

#Player Powerups
def teleport_powerup(user_teleport_display_active):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Teleport Powerup: " + str(user_teleport_display_active), True, red)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (display_width - 205, 5))
def ehealth_powerup(user_health_display_active):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Ehealth Powerup: %s" % user_health_display_active, True, red)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (display_width - 205, 25))

#Game Stats   
def enemies_dodged(enemy_objects_dodged):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged UIO: " + str(enemy_objects_dodged), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (5, 5))
def game_level(game_display_score):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    game_display_score = game_level_score + 1
    text = font.render("Game Level: " + str(game_display_score), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (5, 25))
def session_deaths(deaths_this_session):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Session Deaths: " + str(deaths_this_session), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (display_width - 150, 630))
def bot_speed(enemy_speed):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Bot Speed: " + str(enemy_speed), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (5, 560))
def clock_speed(clockTick):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Clock Tick: " + str(clockTick), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (5, 630))
def clock_speed_intro(clockTick):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Clock Tick: " + str(clockTick), True, green)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (5, 630))


#Sprite Definitions    
def enemies(enemyx, enemyy):
    gameDisplay.blit(enemyImg, (enemy_startx, enemy_starty))
def enemies_two(enemy_twox, enemy_twoy):
    gameDisplay.blit(enemytwoImg, (enemy_two_startx, enemy_two_starty))
def rocket(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(rocketImg, (x, y))
def background(cen1, cen2):
    gameDisplay.blit(backgroundImg, (cen1, cen2))

#Message Display   
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, blue)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect() 
def message_display(text):
    global game_completed
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 70)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    if game_completed == True:
        time.sleep(60)
        game_intro()

    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        if game_level_score > 0:
            pass
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        game_loop()

#User Crash
def crash():
    injuredSound.play()
    message_display("You Died. Game Over!")

#Button Usage
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont(None,20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

#Quit
def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

#Game Intro
def game_intro():
    global clockTick
    global game_level_score
    global user_teleport_active
    global user_teleport_display_active
    global user_health_active
    global user_health_inactive
    global user_health_display_active
    global enemy_speed
    global enemy_two_speed
    global enemies_per_level

    intro = True
    cen1 = (0)
    cen2 = (0)

    enemy_speed = (random.randrange(5, 10))
    enemy_two_speed = (random.randrange(5, 10))
    enemies_per_level = (5)

    game_level_score = (0)
    user_teleport_active = False
    user_teleport_display_active = ("False")
    user_health_active = False
    user_health_inactive = False
    user_health_display_active = ("False")

    while intro:
        clockTick = clock.get_fps()

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quitgame()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None, 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Space Dodge", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2),(display_height / 2))
        background(cen1, cen2)
        clock_speed_intro(clockTick)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Start", display_width / 2.2, 370, 100, 50, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Quit", display_width / 2.2, 445, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

#Game Loop   
def game_loop():
    global left
    global right
    global playerDead
    global musicStopped

    global game_level_score
    global enemy_speed
    global enemy_two_speed
    global game_completed
    global user_teleport_active
    global user_teleport_display_active
    global user_health_active
    global user_health_display_active
    global user_health_inactive
    global deaths_this_session
    global enemies_per_level
    global enemy_startx
    global enemy_starty
    global enemy_two_startx
    global enemy_two_starty

    x = (display_width * 0.43)
    y = (display_height * 0.74)
    cen1 = (0)
    cen2 = (0)
    x_change = 0

    rocket_width = (86)
    game_score = (0)
    enemy_objects_dodged = (0)

    enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    enemy_starty = -600
    enemy_width = 75
    enemy_height = 75

    enemy_two_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    enemy_two_starty = -600
    enemy_two_width = 125
    enemy_two_height = 125

    while not playerDead:
        clockTick = clock.get_fps()

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                quitgame()

            if devMode == True:
                print(event)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    left = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    right = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    left = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    right = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_KP4:
                    left = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_KP6:
                    right = True

                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    game_intro()

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    pass

                if event.key == pygame.K_m:
                    if musicStopped == False:
                        musicStopped = True
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    elif musicStopped == True:
                        musicStopped = False
                        pygame.mixer.music.play()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or pygame.K_d:
                    left = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    right = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    left = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    right = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_KP4:
                    left = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_KP6:
                    right = False

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    pass

        if left and right:
            x_change *= 1
        elif left and x > -86:
            x_change = -10
        elif right and x < (display_width - 89):
            x_change = 10
        else:
            x_change = 0

        if game_level_score > 999:
            quitgame()

        if enemy_objects_dodged == enemies_per_level:
            enemy_speed += 0.5
            enemy_two_speed + 0.5
            game_level_score += 1
            enemies_per_level += 3

            if game_level_score == 999:
                game_completed = True
                message_display('Game Complete! You Win! :D')

            else:
                message_display('You Completed Level: ' + str(game_level_score))
        if user_health_inactive == False:
            if game_level_score > 9:
                user_health_active = True
                user_health_display_active = ("True")
        if game_level_score > 4:
            user_teleport_active = True
            user_teleport_display_active = ("True")

        if user_teleport_active == True:

            if x < -0:
                x = 1330

        if enemy_starty > display_height:
            enemy_starty = 0 - enemy_height
            enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            game_score += 1
            enemy_objects_dodged += 1

        if enemy_two_starty > display_height:
            enemy_two_starty = 0 - enemy_two_height
            enemy_two_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            game_score += 1
            enemy_objects_dodged += 1

        if y < enemy_starty + enemy_height:

            if x > enemy_startx and x < enemy_startx + enemy_width or x + rocket_width > enemy_startx and x + rocket_width < enemy_startx + enemy_width:
                if user_health_active:
                    x = (display_width * 0.43)
                    y = (display_height * 0.74)

                    user_health_active = False
                    user_health_display_active = False
                    user_health_inactive = True

                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    deaths_this_session += 1
                    crash()

        if y < enemy_two_starty + enemy_two_height:

            if x > enemy_two_startx and x < enemy_two_startx + enemy_two_width or x + rocket_width > enemy_two_startx and x + rocket_width < enemy_two_startx + enemy_two_width:
                if user_health_active:
                    x = (display_width * 0.43)
                    y = (display_height * 0.74)

                    user_health_active = False
                    user_health_display_active = False
                    user_health_inactive = True

                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    deaths_this_session += 1
                    crash()

        x += x_change

        background(cen1, cen2)
        enemies(enemy_startx, enemy_starty)
        enemies_two(enemy_two_startx, enemy_two_starty)
        enemy_starty += enemy_speed
        enemy_two_starty += enemy_two_speed
        rocket(x, y)
        enemies_dodged(enemy_objects_dodged)
        game_level(game_display_score)
        clock_speed(clockTick)
        session_deaths(deaths_this_session)
        teleport_powerup(user_teleport_display_active)
        ehealth_powerup(user_health_display_active)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(90)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.20)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    game_intro()
```

Setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import *
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "SpaceDodge",
    author = "theoiestinapps",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["pygame"], "include_files": ["game_background_music.mp3", "background_image.png", "enemy_image.png",
                                                                       "player_image.png", "player_hurt_sound.wav", "game_error_sound.wav"]},
               "bdist_msi": {"upgrade_code": "{9d3d322e74744a1282ce1ea2c5af2676}"}},
    executables = [Executable("SpaceDodge.py", shortcutName = "SpaceDodge", shortcutDir = "DesktopFolder", base = base)]
    )
```

Comment: A word to the wise: Use a version control system such as Git to find out what changed since your last working version and debug using that information.

Comment: To clarify, this doesn't have any problems when not frozen? It could be many things, especially because of the significant dependency on exact filepaths (which is almost always a *bad idea*). If you can't use a Python debugger, edit the code and throw `print` statements everywhere. That's better than nothing.

Comment: @Kupiakos Yes, the program has absolutely no issues when frozen. Also you have mentioned Git. Though not related to my question, where can I properly learn to use Git?

Comment: I learned from the [source](https://git-scm.com/). There's a [tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) hosted by [Github](https://github.com/) as well as the official book [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control). To be frank though, your Python could also definitely use some work. Check out [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) to improve your code. Globals, avoiding classes, and absolute file paths are big no-nos.

Comment: @Kupiakos Well, thank you. I guess I'm screwed with my game though.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Like I suggested, try putting print statements all throughout the initialization of the program (making sure that the application is a console application and not a GUI application so you have a console to look at) and finding out where the prints stop to see where it actually dies. Or, even better, take this as an opportunity to learn the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.

Comment: @Kupiakos I'll look into it. The program apparently died to not having freesansbold.ttf despite it never being used. After that I ran into a cx_Freeze error.

Answer (score 0):

N.B.: I have no experience with `cx_Freeze`, and neither with pygame so my answer is only a "feeling" of what might be fishy, and where I'd look first if I was actually debugging the code:

at many places in your code you're changing font size by using:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
```

As you give `None` as parameter for the font name, the documentation says:

> If a suitable system font is not found this will fallback on loading the default pygame font.

when you're packing your app to make it a self contained .exe, it's likely that cx_Freeze is trying to get the "default" font, and assumes (wrongly) that it is 
`freesansbold.ttf` that it couldn't find or put as a resource with the .exe. And then, it might refer to that font relatively to/within the .exe, without having it copied, making the code crash.

though, when you run it with the python interpreter, the font resolution is going through the system and works appropriately, as it is supposed to.

To validate my theory, you can remove/comment all references to font changes (making your code look likely to look ugly), try to .exe it again and see if it works. You can also printout:

```
pygame.font.get_default_font()
```

in both context and see if it's showing up the same file.

That's my two cents, hope it'll help